# neo4j-admin import: Directory of import\movies5b.csv doesn't exist

Tags: neo4j

I tried to follow [this example.](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/#import-tool-same-relationship-type-for-every-relationship-example) But somehow it cant access or find the import directory or the files located in it.

```
 C:\Program Files\Neo4j EE 3.2.2\neo4j-enterprise-3.3.2\bin>neo4j-admin import --nodes import/movies5b.csv --nodes import/actors5b.csv --relationships:ACTED_IN import/roles5b.csv
 Directory of import\movies5b.csv doesn't exist
```

I only did copy paste. This is my path to movies5b.csv `C:\Program Files\Neo4j EE 3.2.2\neo4j-enterprise-3.3.2\import`. I copied the name and I cant find any typos. I can open all csv's and they contain everything they should. I started the command prompt as admin. There are no changes in the log. Neo4j isnt started. `NEO4J_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files\Neo4j EE 3.2.2\neo4j-enterprise-3.3.2`.

Comment: Try moving the server to a path with no spaces, like c:\neo4j-enterprise332

Comment: I will try this on monday. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this `neo4j-admin import`, path  are relative to where you execute it.

Because you execute it under the `bin` folder, the tool can't find your csv.

Try to prefix your CSV path with `../` or (`..\` for windows ?)  or run the same command but from the Neo4j home directory

Comment: I tried the both / \ i will try again on monday thanks for the answer.

Comment: It was the path. I put the files into the existing `import` directory. After moving it to the `bin\import` it worked fine.